# Best way to search the Entire Active Directory for one user

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Can someone assist me in how can I search all of AD for a users, who I would not know if exist or not.

Root domain (NA1.local)

Resource Domain (domain1.local, domain2.local, domain3.local)

MSmith  (not sure where in the domain he\she is located or if the userid has been deleted from AD) 
$user = PSmith

```
foreach ($domain in $domains)
{
  Get-ADUser -Identity $username -Server $domain  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($? -eq 'True') { 
                $forest = Get-ADUser $username -Server $domain
                Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $GPName -Member $forest -Server $VbrickSrv } 
}
```

Comment: `Get-ADUser` will throw an ObjectNotFound error if the user isn't found.

Comment: If you want to rely on `$?`, you need to use `-Filter` instead of `-Identity` in the `Get-ADUser` command: `Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$username'" -Server $domain  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. That will return $null if the user is not found and there are no other issues with the command.

Comment: Expanding on what @JeffZeitlin said, if you put the command in a `try-catch` block it  should work with handling the error.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the username with the `-Filter` or `-LDAPFilter` vs. the `-Identity` parameter. The filters are usually faster because they do the filtering on the DC instead of locally on the machine running the script. Also, the cmdlet won't generate an exception if nothing is returned when using the filter (over the identity) parameters.

```
$user = Get-ADUser -Filter { SamAccountName -eq 'psmith' }
...
```

I normally tell you to set the search base to whatever makes sense for your search. The more restrictive the better, but I see you want to search the entire domain. Just keep that in the back of your mind.

Check the following article out for a deeper discussion.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28485.filters-with-powershell-active-directory-module-cmdlets.aspx

Comment: Yes, *always* filter and use a `searchbase` if at all possible. With `*` as your filter and a `where` clause, you're very expensively searching through all the accounts rather than the ones you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

As well as what @Adam said about using a filter rather than a `where` clause (which is the proper answer) , you can simplify your code a bit when you find the user

```
foreach ($domain in $domains) {
    If ($u = Get-ADUser -Filter 'SamAccountName -eq "psmith"' -server $domain) {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $GPName -Members $u -Server $domain
        Break  #this should exit from the foreach loop
    }
}
```